# React express js (webpack 5) not serving or loading the js.gz files in browser

Tags: reactjs, express, compression, webpack-5

I am trying to update webpack 5 for my React express js (server side rendering app) after updating the compression plugin and webpack 5, the output of the files are in format `*.js.gz` while before the update it was `*.js`

After this update the javascript file is not getting loaded in the browser. what is causing this issue?

Express.js

```js
app.use(compression());
app.use(getRequestLogger());
app.use(getErrorLogger());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(requestInterceptor);
app.use(express.static('public', {...config.cacheConfig, setHeaders}));
app.use(expressContext.middleware);
```

Webpack compression

```js
const path = require('path');
const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');
const { DefinePlugin, IgnorePlugin } = require('webpack');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const LoadablePlugin = require('@loadable/webpack-plugin');
const CompressionPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin');

function getEnvironmentConfig(envConfig, env) {
  return envConfig[env.BUILD_ENV] || envConfig.dev || {};
}

const copyPlugin = new CopyWebpackPlugin(
  { patterns: [{ from: './src/public/favicon.ico' }] },
  {
    copyUnmodified: true,
  },
);
const reactLoadablePlugin = new LoadablePlugin({
  filename: '../loadable-stats.json',
});

const DashboardPlugin = require('webpack-dashboard/plugin');

const { BundleAnalyzerPlugin } = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer');
const commonConfig = require('./webpack.base');

/**
 * Gets the Webpack configuration for the React bundle.
 *
 * @param {{ BUILD_ENV: string }} env
 *   The Webpack environment.
 */
const compressionPlugin = new CompressionPlugin({
  test: /\.js$|\.css$|\.html$|\.json$/,
  algorithm: 'gzip',
  deleteOriginalAssets: true,
  // [path] is a path relative to output.path
  exclude: '../loadable-stats.json',
  minRatio: Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER,
});

function reactConfig(env) {
  return merge(
    commonConfig(env),
    {
      target: 'web',
      devtool: 'source-map',
      entry: {
        main: path.resolve(__dirname, 'web/client.js'),
        landingPage: path.resolve(
          __dirname,
          'somejs.js',
        ),
        wrapper: path.resolve(__dirname, 'web/wrapper.js'),
        wrapper2: path.resolve(__dirname, 'web/cha.js'),
      },
      output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
        publicPath: '',
      },
      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: [
              {
                loader: 'style-loader',
              },
              {
                loader: 'css-loader',
                options: {
                  url: false,
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      plugins: [
        reactLoadablePlugin,
        new DefinePlugin({
          'process.env.WEBPACK_TARGET': JSON.stringify('web'),
          'process.env.FLAVOR': JSON.stringify(env.BUILD_ENV),
        }),
        new IgnorePlugin({
          resourceRegExp: /^\.\/i18n\/data/,
          contextRegExp: /@components\/other-app-complied-inwebpack4\/dist$/,
        }),
        compressionPlugin,
      ],
      optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
          chunks: 'initial',
          maxInitialRequests: 1,
        },
      },
    },
    getEnvironmentConfig(
      {
        prod: {
          plugins: [copyPlugin],
        },
        dev: {
          plugins: [
            copyPlugin,
            new DashboardPlugin(),
            new BundleAnalyzerPlugin(),
          ],
        },
      },
      env,
    ),
  );
}

module.exports = (env = { BUILD_ENV: 'dev' }) => {
  if (!env.BUILD_ENV || env.BUILD_ENV === '$FLAVOR') {
    env.BUILD_ENV = 'dev';
  }
  const config = [reactConfig(env)];
  if (env.WEBPACK_LOG_LEVEL === 'VERBOSE') {
    console.log(
      'Final config',
      JSON.stringify(
        config,
        (key, value) =>
          value instanceof RegExp ? `[RegExp(${value.toString()})]` : value,
        2,
      ),
    );
  }
  return config;
};
```

[image]

[image]